# Why is it good practice to use namespaced urls in Django?

Tags: python, django, namespaces

I have followed a number of tutorials and read the following link from the Django docs. It is supposed to be good practice to use namespaced url's (e.g. 'polls:index') instead of hardcoding them.

I cannot fully understand why this is important, apart from convenience. Why exactly is this good practice and what problems could it help avoid?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Comment: You won't really notice the use in a simple app. But once you have hundreds routes and you want to restructure your app in some way or change a URL. Imagine if that URL is used a bunch of times in 10 different files. If it's hardcoded you're going to have to do a sketchy search and replace, or do it all by hand. If you namespaced it, you don't have to worry about any of that. You define the URL in one place, and then just use references to it everywhere else. It's the same as making a function for something you do more than once instead of writing it all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is already answered [in another section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) of the same documentation page (emphasis mine):

> It is strongly desirable to avoid hard-coding these URLs (a laborious, non-scalable and error-prone strategy). Equally dangerous is devising ad-hoc mechanisms to generate URLs that are parallel to the design described by the URLconf, which can result in the production of URLs that become stale over time.
>
> In other words, what’s needed is a DRY mechanism. **Among other advantages it would allow evolution of the URL design without having to go over all the project source code to search and replace outdated URLs.**

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see this section. And that's a good explanation you gave regarding the URL design.